# VPS reinicia configuración nginx solo

Tags: nginx, cpanel, vps

espero me puedan ayudar, tengo un problema con mi configuración Nginx.

Dentro de mi servidor VPS con cPanel tengo instalado NGINX® Manager apuntando a un dominio de varios que tengo.
Todo funciona correctamente cuando lo configuro, el problema es que una vez durante la noche se reinicia la configuración que tengo en el archivo .conf a como estaba por default de uno de mis dominios probocando que se caiga la página a la que esta direccionado.

He buscado si tengo jobs activos que puedan provocar pero no he encontrado algo relacionado, no sé si sea alguna configuración externa que me esté afectando

Espero me puedan apoyar o si han tenido algún problema similar, me comenten como lo solucionaron.

Gracias.

Comment: Habría que revisar qué configuración hay en tu VPS para que se sobreescriba. No es de nginx sino del entorno y ahí sí depende exclusivamente de las políticas que apliquen en tu caso

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.